# Add different ID to 2 different Bootstrap modal-backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have 2 modals on a page, each modal have different behaviors, one modal is transformed into a page content if the page is bigger than a specified width. To enable that I have used jQuery to hide its modal-backdrop but the problem is that the script will also hide the backdrop for the 2nd modal which has normal behavior. How can I assign a different ID for each modal-backdrop?

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
  Launch modal with modal-backdrop id 1
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Launch modal with modal-backdrop id 2
</button>




<!-- Modal1 modal-backdrop id 1-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal2 modal-backdrop id 2-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Well you need to post minimal code explaining your problem! Or else how it is possible for us to even guess what's happening.. :)

Comment: It is hard to add a example because the code has over 1200 lines :D. As long as it is standard Bootstrap i thought is generally known what modal-backdrop is. It is generated by the Bootstrap modal plugin in the HTML body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `bootstrap` modal's `.on('show.bs.modal'` event to make changes to your backdrop accordingly like one below:

```
$("#myModal1,#myModal2").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var that=$(this);
    var id=that.attr('id'); //get the id of button which got clicked
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.modal-backdrop').attr('data-id',id);
        //You can either assign it as data-* attribute or add it as class to backdrop like
        //$('.modal-backdrop').addClass(id);
    });
});
```

Now accordingly you can use this to make changes according to modal's behavior.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/o0ygwy0n/)**

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" >
```